# centering header tag issue

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this question has been asked before but here goes...

I am trying to center a h3 tag on my page. I would just like to use inline style to accomplish this.

Now i have read the easiest way to auto center something is to:

```
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
```

problem is that's not working for me. Its still lining up on the left hand side.
sure i could guess the margin-left pixels amount to get close but....

why wont it center it?

my actually code:

```
<h3 style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">To make a donation now. Click the button
below!!</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a width in order to center with margin when its a block.

```
<h3 style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 300px;">To make a donation now. Click the button
below!!</h3>
```

if you just want to center the text inside the block you can use `text-align: center`

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">To make a donation now. Click the button
below!!</h3>
```